# Convert emf to PNG image using command line

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, image-processing

Is there any command line tool available to convert emf to png images?

I tried the `convert` utility from ImageMagick, but it says

```
decoder for emf not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this page: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

> EMF  R  Microsoft Enhanced Metafile (32-bit)  Only available under Microsoft Windows.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063349/running-imagemagick-on-linux-to-convert-emf-to-png)

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes?

Comment: I did not downvote but it's annoying to have an accepted answer with information that do not help to solve the problem and only partially answer the question when there is two answers that do below.

Answer (score 15):

(Found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/28749719)

Use LibreOffice:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to png image.emf
```

Comment: `--convert-to pdf` is also allowed!

Comment: may require cropping after the conversion, though

Answer (score 9):

The other answers here did not work for me, but [one I found on stakoverflow did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38589531/4893482)

> Another way is to use inkscape:
>
> ```
> inkscape -e file.png source.emf
> ```
>
> See inkscape --help for more export options (area to export, dpi, image resolution, background color etc).

Comment: works fine under Bionic with inkscape v0.92.3

Answer (score 0):

inkscape is a great idea, but unfortunately it does not do a perfect job, for ex. with label positions getting messed in certain cases, as described here: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/2847

So far the only accurate conversion outside of Windows that I've seen is with OpenOffice (headless) or using the unoconv Python script which calls OpenOffice/LibreOffice to do the work. Maybe there's some way to hack together ImageMagick and Mono (libgdi) under Linux but haven't found anything that's done that yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the good library [libemf2svg](https://github.com/kakwa/libemf2svg) and after [imagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php)

Install library libemf2svg, example for debian or ubuntu:

```bsh
git clone git@github.com:kakwa/libemf2svg.git
cd libemf2svg/
sudo apt-get install gcc g++ cmake libpng-dev libfreetype-dev libfontconfig1-dev -y
cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/
make
sudo make install
```

Use the lib by
`./emf2svg-conv  -i test.emf -o test.svg`
Now you have a svg file.
Finally, finish the convert by
`convert test.svg test.png`